# Passing an object to a modal in a partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a modal partial view I'm showing on a page, that needs to see the parent object.

The modal is launched via an ActionLink.  I see no way to have this modal see the parent object.  I have set the partial view's model property to the parent object's model but it can't see it.

It seems that this all has to be serialized through the querystring?   Is there a better way to do this?   I have complex types (such as List<>) in the parent object and for security reasons I don't want this passed through the querystring, if it even can.

Do I have to set a ViewBag property to the parent object?

What are my options here?

Comment: Without seeing an example (which I urge you to supply), I am running on the assumption that you mean you are creating an ActionLink on a view.  ActionLink is simply forming an `<a>` tag in html.  It can't pass an object like you want.  When the user clicks the link, its a new view event.

Comment: Right, so basically I can't show a modal in a partial view.  How would I handle this best then?  I need them to click a link on a page that displays a modal, but the modal needs to see the parent view's object.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the object to the partialview in order for it to be seen.

In the View:

```
@Html.Action("ChildView", "Controller", new { foo = Model.foo})
```

In the Controller:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult ChildView(Foo foo)
{            
     return View(foo);
}
```

If you don't want to pass it as shown above, you could always keep the object in state.

Comment: I have a return PartialView() though ... the modal displays, but it can't see the parent object.  And I thought through this route the parent view's Model will be sent via the QueryString, which I can't have.

Comment: Take a look at this link to get an idea of which to use when considering temp data. http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/9KHW190712-ViewData-vs-ViewBag-vs-TempData-vs-Session.html

Comment: Have you considered implementing a jquery modal? This would also prevent any GET requests as the data is already on the page.

Comment: I have tried getting the object through the ViewBag but it doesn't seem to work.  Shouldn't a partial launched via an ActionLink be able to see the properties of the parent's ViewBag?

Comment: The ViewBag is only available through the ActionResult that initialized it.  You can have a ViewBag.MyCustomObject in both Actions, but the child Action will always win.

Comment: That page specifically says "then you can only access the model which you pass to your partial view", which is exactly what I'm trying to do.  Unfortunately it doesn't explain how to do that.  Am I going to have to use ViewData or something similar for this?  I am not sure how the model binder would handle this on the repost of the form.  It's all the same object, it's just that some of the properties are completed on a modal.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93828/discussion-between-ian-and-patrick).